# How can I return multiple components on App.js file?

Tags: reactjs

I have this module with two functional components and want to render them in App.js

```
import React from 'react';

function IteractionSample() {
    const names = ['gi', 'hello', 'hiiii'];
    const nameList = names.map(
        (name) => (<li>{name}</li>)
    );
    return(
        <ul>
            {nameList}
        </ul>
    )
}

function IteractionSample1() {
    const names = ['232123', '343', '123123'];
    const nameList = names.map(
        (name) => (<li>{name}</li>)
    );
    return(
        <ul>
            {nameList}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default {IteractionSample, IteractionSample1};
```

My App.js file is like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import IteractionSample from './IterationSample';
import IteractionSample1 from './IterationSample';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <IteractionSample />
            <IteractionSample1 />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and Index.js file like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

On Google Dev tools, I can see that I am getting an error on

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I tried multiple things. But, I can't get those two functional components on my page at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [exporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) a single default object containing the two functional components in `App.js` and trying to [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) two defaults in `index.js`. Only one default can be exported. In `App.js` you are importing the default object twice (storing it in different variables) and later you are trying to use that object as `React` components, so `ReactDOM.render` will complain about it.

If you export a default object containing your two components:

```
export default { IteractionSample, IteractionSample1 };
```

Then you need to import that unique object:

```
import myObjectSamples from './IterationSample';
const { IteractionSample, IteractionSample1 } = myObjectSamples;
```

But if you want to import the components directly from `index.js`, then it is better that you use named exports:

```
export function IteractionSample() {
    ...
}

export function IteractionSample1() {
    ...
}
```

Then you can import those components in `index.js`:

```
import { IteractionSample, IteractionSample1 } from './IterationSample';
```

Answer (score 2):

As i know, you can export one thing in your export default,
In order to export 2 function, use like this:

```
export const myfunction= your function codes here
export  const myfunction2 = your    function codes here
```

Then in your app.js import like this :

```
import {myfunction , myfunction2} from "path"
```

I hope you get the idea and works for you

Comment: It’s called named export.

Comment: He is exporting one thing as default, the mistake is importing it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the same file, do something similar to:

```
const IteractionSample = () => {

};

const IteractionSample1 = () => {

};

module.exports = {
    IteractionSample,
    IteractionSample1
}
```

Then in your `app.js`

```
import { IteractionSample, IteractionSample1 }  from './IterationSample';
```

**Note:** There are better solutions to this, but this should keep you progressing forward

Answer (score 0):

use [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

```
export const IteractionSample1 = () => {
    const names = ['232123', '343', '123123'];
    const nameList = names.map(
        (name) => (<li>{name}</li>)
    );
    return(
        <ul>
            {nameList}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

// Usage

```
import { IteractionSample1 } from './IterationSample';
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on line 2 & 3 in App.js file.
You are trying to import the **function component** as a **class component**.
Replace line 2 & 3 with below line

```
import {IteractionSample,IteractionSample1 } from './IterationSample';
```

Comment: The issue is that he is trying to import the same `default` object two times and then is trying to use that object as `React` components (The error is in the `ReactDOM.render` line). There is no difference importing a functional component, a class, a constant, an object or any other declaration. To make that you are proposing, he needs to export the components as named components. Check the rest of the answers.